# cannot find module: jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

We are using jest for the UT and angular framework. Most of the errors are stating 'Cannot find module' so I re-imported the reference but still nothing happened. The reference import is correctly placed.

Snippet of the error:

```
src/app/test/routing/app-routing.spec.ts

Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/services/common/common-helper.service' from 'src/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts'

Require stack:
  src/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts
  src/app/app-routing.module.ts
  src/app/test/routing/app-routing.spec.ts
```

======================================

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
    BACK_BUTTON_LABEL,
    CONTINUE_BUTTON_LABEL,
} from '../../util/constants/label.constant';
import { provinceNameAndCodes } from '../../util/constants/app.constants';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FORM_INVALID_CLASS } from '../../util/constants/validator.constants';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CommonHelperService {
    formInvalidClass: string = FORM_INVALID_CLASS;
    private closeBtnBehaveSubj = new Subject<string>();
    private isMobileSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    private progressCountPerInputField = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    currentProgressCount = this.progressCountPerInputField.asObservable();
    private isDeliSameAsResSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    setIsDeliSameAsResSubj(event: boolean): void {
        this.isDeliSameAsResSubject.next(event);
    }

    getIsDeliSameAsResSubj(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.isDeliSameAsResSubject.asObservable();
    }

    setCloseBtnSubj(event: string): void {
        this.closeBtnBehaveSubj.next(event);
    }

    getCloseBtnSubj(): Observable<string> {
        return this.closeBtnBehaveSubj.asObservable();
    }

    setIsMobileSubject(event: boolean): void {
        this.isMobileSubject.next(event);
    }

    getIsMobileSubject(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.isMobileSubject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
    }

    changeProgressCountPerField(progressCountPerField: number) {
        this.progressCountPerInputField.next(progressCountPerField);
    }

    getCurrentPageIndex(
        noOfScreens: number,
        btnType: string,
        currentPageIndex: number
    ): number {
        if (btnType === CONTINUE_BUTTON_LABEL) {
            if (currentPageIndex != noOfScreens) {
                return (currentPageIndex += 1);
            }
        } else if (btnType === BACK_BUTTON_LABEL) {
            if (currentPageIndex > 0) {
                return (currentPageIndex -= 1);
            }
        }
    }

    getProvinceCode(provinceText: string): any {
        const provinceCode = provinceNameAndCodes.find(row => {
            return (
                row.name.trim().toLowerCase() ===
                provinceText.trim().toLowerCase()
            );
        });
        return provinceCode ? provinceCode.value : '';
    }

    setRequiredErrorState(
        form: FormGroup,
        mandatoryFieldsArr: string[],
        el: ElementRef
    ): void {
        mandatoryFieldsArr.forEach((control: string) => {
            if (!form.controls[control].value.trim()) {
                form.controls[control].setErrors({ incorrect: true });
            }
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.scrollToError(el);
        }, 0);
    }

    scrollToError(el: ElementRef): void {
        const firstElementWithError: HTMLElement =
            el.nativeElement.querySelector(this.formInvalidClass);
        if (firstElementWithError) {
            firstElementWithError.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'center',
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share how you have imported and exported and unit tested (mocked services)

Comment: @Ismail post has been updated

Comment: Hi there! could you add the unit test file too? That issue looks like it's caused by the import, so it would be super useful to see that import line :D